# Passing range objects to functions in excel-vba -- receive "Object Required" error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to build a function that will take an input cell (say "B5") and return a range object that refers to a table (of which the supplied cell is the top-right entry)

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim testCell As Range

testCell = Worksheets("HMA").Range("B5")
ReturnTable testCell

End Sub

Function ReturnTable(cell As Range)
    firstcell = cell
    lastrow = firstcell.End(x1Down)
    Table = Range(firstcell, lastrow + 5).Value
End Function
```

I've been running into a lot of problems here, and I feel like I'm missing something simple. The error that I'm getting is "Object Required" at the lastRow line.

Looking through it in debug mode I see that testCell is assigned the value of the range object (I assume this is the default). What am I missing here?

Is my approach even sound? Should I be looking at solving this problem in a different way?

Comment: You need to use `Set` when assigning the value of testCell (or any other object variable), otherwise you're assigning the default property of the range (in this case `.Value`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The End returns a Range object, so, lastrow must be a range variable.

```
Function ReturnTable(firstcell as Range) as Range 'add this as range to tell the result of the function is a range
    dim LastCell as Range
    Set LastCell = firstcell.END(xldown)
    Set ReturnTable = Range(firstcell, lastcell) 'must use the same name of the function
End Function
```

If you want 5 cells below lastcell, use `LastCell.Offset(5,0)`

And in Macro1, you probably will want something like

```
Set SomeVar = ReturnTable(testcell)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you assign Objects (like Range) you have to use "Set".

If you assign Range without "Set" VBA will assign the value of the Range and not the Range itself.

```
Set testCell = Worksheets("HMA").Range("B5")
```